# Why update the same time?

Tags: applications

What I want to ask is usually android app not update but in someday those will have a tons of update and I can ensure that it is not my phone problem. So why apps usually update the same time ? Any reasonal explain for this ?

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting your question properly, you are basically asking why sometimes you see many apps update all at once.

The answer is simple: it is more efficient to update many apps at once.

In Android, especially in Android N+, emphasis is placed on network and CPU performance and optimization when running tasks.

When a developer wants to run a background task, they can create a job and register it with the Android system to run under certain conditions.  This creates a convenient way to run tasks in a batch, thus being more device resource friendly.  Jobs that are enqueued by the system can kick off and run based on device conditions/properties, like: "when the device is charging" or "when the device is on an unmetered network".

Google Play, for example, queues up app updates when the device is on Wi-Fi networks or while plugged in.  You can change the behavior of app updates in Settings.

[image: Google Play Auto-Update Settings]

This is why you will often see many apps update after plugging in your device or hopping onto you home Wi-Fi network.

Comment: I always set it to auto update and I usually check for update app 1 a day but it like today I don't see anything tommorow don't see anything tommorow of tommorow don't see and then after that suddenly a bunch of app just update but I understand what you're saying

Comment: I also get what your are observing - it is strange how Google Play will push suddenly, lots of apps at once.  My hunch is that big-name app developers obviously won't push an update out on Friday because if there are issues, no one will be around on the weekend to fix them.  So to mitigate risk, I suspect most updates are pushed out early during the work week.

Comment: Yeah tks for that  I Think thật make sense much